# How to change values in a data.frame column into numbers?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, tidyr, tidyverse

I have the following (sample) data.frame

```
x <- data.frame(gene = 1:3, Sample1 = 5:7, Sample2 = 4:6, Sample3 = 6:8)
```

I want to change the column names and then use the numbers in the new titles as x-axis values for my plot

```
colnames(x) <- c("Gene", "HeLa_0.2", "HeLa_2.0", "HeLa_5.0")

x_gather <- x %>%
  gather(key=treatment, value=values, -c(Gene)) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(treatment, into=c("Cell_line", "treatment"),sep="_")

ggplot()+
  geom_line(x_gather, mapping=aes(treatment, y=values, group=Gene))
```

But I want the numbers to be spaced on an x-axis like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n2fQ.png), instead of on an axis like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsddV.png) (which I get only if I copy my data to excel, format them as numbers, and then load it into R again...)
Any suggestions to how to solve this?

Thanks!  :)

Comment: You need to use `convert = TRUE` in `separate` to convert to new types.  Right now `treatment` is a character.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm quite new to R, as you understand :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make the `treatment` variable numeric. For instance:

```
x_gather <- x %>%
  gather(key=treatment, value=values, -c(Gene)) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(treatment, into=c("Cell_line", "treatment"),sep="_") %>%
  mutate(treatment = as.numeric(treatment))

ggplot()+
  geom_line(x_gather, mapping=aes(treatment, y=values, group=Gene))
```

[image]

Comment: I have to use %>% mutate(as.numeric(treatment), but then it works
:)